# How do I connect to a remote svn server?

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, ssh, version

Heres the current setup.

**Home PC** ---/ *Internet* /---> **Work Proxy Server** --/ *LAN* /--> **SVN server**

- Home PC running Windows XP.
- Work Proxy server running fedora-core (to which I can connect through ssh).
- SVN server is inside the Office LAN running Windows XP.

I want to connect to the work svn server commit changes, update and checkout from the home PC.

I can tunnel to my Work SVN PC (not the service) with no problems, which I currently use with VNC (using PuTTY).

Currently using Tortoisesvn for a client.

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your work proxy machine has access to the SVN server, you would set up a tunnel like this with regular SSH: `ssh -L localport:svnserver:svnport username@proxyserver`.  You'll need to figure out the equivalent options for PuTTY, perhaps by using that link Ben S provided.  Once you've set up the tunnel, all your SVN operations will be going through `localport` on your local computer, so you'll need to set up Tortoise to treat your local machine on that port as the SVN server (using either a new checkout or an `svn switch --relocate` on an existing working copy.

Comment: how do I access the repo after that? svn://localhost/svnrepos

Comment: you would access it exactly the same as you normally would, except replace the SVN server's hostname with "localhost".  The URL you gave in your comment could very well be the correct one.

Comment: The host actively refused the connection. Thats what I get, but it works on the server. Oh well, will try find away :) thanks for the help

Comment: I never got around to make it work with svn://* but its working fine with VisualSvn HTTP

Answer (score 2):

You need to configure a tunnel port in PuTTY so that you'll connect to localhost:someport on your home PC, and PuTTY will tunnel all traffic between the two.

Depending on the SVN server setup you'll want to use either port 80 (`http:`), 443 (`https:`)  or 3690 (`svn:`).

[This tutorial](http://oldsite.precedence.co.uk/nc/putty.html) is slightly outdated, but still applies here.

Comment: Thanks Ben, I can tunnel just fine. How do I use the client to commit changes to the server?

Comment: Instead of using the URL you use at work, connect to localhost:3690 (or whatever port you forwarded). This will connect locally to the PuTTY tunnel.

Answer (score 0):

The previous answers may be correct, but are more complicated than necessary. If you specify your repository using the syntax svn+ssh://user@host/path/to/repository, tunneling details will be taken care of, as long as you meet the following requirements:

- you can ssh to the server holding the repository
- you would be able to run 'svnserve' on this server
- you got ssh or a similar command-line utility on your windows client machine

The last item may involve a bit extra work. I had success by:

1. installing Cygwin (with 'openssh' + 'openssl' packages)
2. adding the following line to the [tunnels] section of the SVN 'config' file(*):
     "ssh = /cygwin/bin/ssh -q " (*no* space at the beginning of the line).

(*) You can find it in c:\Documents and Settings\user\Application Data\Subversion, or by going to the TortoiseSVN Settings > General menu, and clicking the 'Edit' button.